# How to acknowledge specific offset on container.stop in Spring Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Basically there is opened *WebSocket* session for logged-in user *id = 123* and listener container have been created and started and records from topic *notification.user.123* are sent to the client but `acknowledgment.acknowledge();` is never really called.

The latest viewed notification and related offset are known. I do not want to store and manage that data and seek for offset. When it is time to close the WebSocket session and stop the listener container I need to acknowledge it. So it will be stored somewhere in broker as the latest offset readed by consumer. And new WebSocket session and listener container will start from that offset naturally.

So far I have tried improvise with no luck with https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#seek and

```
private class MyListener extends AbstractConsumerSeekAware implements AcknowledgingConsumerAwareMessageListener<String, Notification> {
```

Do I need to look at some listener container life cycle and atStop event?

Comment: Why don't you just let the container acknowledge them automatically with `AckMode.RECORD`? If you must use manual acks for some reason, since you are receiving all the topic/partition/offset info you can commit the offsets on the `Consumer` by capturing the `ConsumerStoppoingEvent`s.

Comment: Because notifications may be lost before they are viewed (at browser window close or page refresh).
The suggested solution is working perfectly with `@KafkaListener` and `@EventListener` but there are no events for programmatically created and started `KafkaMessageListenerContainer`. Is it possible to register that bean in the registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use manual acks for some reason, since you are receiving all the topic/partition/offset info you can commit the offsets on the Consumer by capturing the `ConsumerStoppoingEvent`s.

> The suggested solution is working perfectly with `@KafkaListener` and `@EventListener` but there are no events for programmatically created and started KafkaMessageListenerContainer.

To get events to an event listener when Spring doesn't manage the container, call `setApplicationEventPublisher(applictionContext)` (the application publisher is the application context when an `ApplicationEventListenerAware` bean is managed by Spring).

Or you can simply inject your own `ApplicationEventPublisher` implementation and deal with the event(s) there.

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments; and don't put code in comments - as you can see it doesn't render well and is hard to read. What you are suggesting makes no sense; the container won't commit any offsets with that configuration. Ask a new question with a minimal, complete, reproducible example that exhibits this behavior. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example